# Part of an array is not accessed through foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a bot for telegram using Botman and I have an issue when trying to get a value from an API response.

This is my class that proccesses the response and returns the message to the user, you can see the API adress.

```
class TaxiService {

protected $client;
const TAXI_ENDPOINT = 'http://35.204.38.8:4000/api/v1/taxis/%s';

/**
 * DogService constructor
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(){
    $this->client = new Client();
}

public function hireTaxi(){
    try {
        $lon="Hello";
        $endpoint = sprintf(self::TAXI_ENDPOINT, 'Madrid');

        $response = json_decode(
            $this->client->get($endpoint)->getBody()
        );

        foreach($response as $key => $value){
            foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
                if(is_array($value2)){
                    foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3){
                        $lon = $value3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $lon;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // If anything goes wrong, we will be sending the user this error message.
        return 'An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.';
    }
}
```

}

This is the response I get when calling the API.

```
[{"state":"free","name":"Opel","location": 
 {"lon":1.399,"lat":38.88},"city":"Madrid"}, 
 {"state":"free","name":"Skoda4","location": 
 {"lon":1.3123,"lat":38.123},"city":"Madrid"}, 
 {"state":"free","name":"Hyundai","location": 
 {"lon":1.2313,"lat":38.41},"city":"Madrid"}]
```

When I iterate trough the Array given by ´json_decode´ the ´$long´ variable returns ´Hello´, it doesn't set any value when looping trough the array.

What I want to get is one of the values in the location position of the JSON.

I have tested my function with this site: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and it gives me a value belonging to the JSON which is what I want but it seems the function is not working in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change:

```
$response = json_decode(
    $this->client->get($endpoint)->getBody()
);
```

to:

```
$response = json_decode(
    $this->client->get($endpoint)->getBody(), true
);
```

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: Right, as if you don't pass true as a second argument you're getting an stdObject and not an array.

Comment: I had to edit my question, I had $lon = $key3 but it was meant to be $lon = $value3; I added true to json_decode and didn't work, now it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @NeoChiri check your API response. I've just run your example and works fine. What is expected result ?

Comment: It works now, it must have been an API issue, maybe a small downtime, I don't know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value of `$lon` on each iteration, which probably isn't what you want. If you just want the lon from the first record that was returned, then you don't need to iterate over everything, just explicitly take the first one:

```
$response = json_decode(
    $this->client->get($endpoint)->getBody()
);
return $response[0]->location->lon;
```

Or even:

```
return json_decode($this->client->get($endpoint)->getBody())[0]->location->lon;
```

Answer (score -1):

neoChiri,

Looks like a scope issue. You would get a `$long is not defined` error if the variable doesn't exist. So, some variable you created later on in the code is masking the original value.

Hope this helps.